# Grouping DataFrame combining column values

Tags: python, dataframe, group

```
d = {'Location':['Fridge','Fridge','Pantry','Pantry'], 'Food': ['Juice','Ham','Rice','Oil']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to create a new DataFrame that groups all the Locations but combines their respective foods. So under 'Fridge' I would see 'Juice, Ham'. Groupby seems the logical function, but I can't get the foods combined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for `.groupby()` & `agg()`!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Location":["Fridge","Fridge","Pantry","Pantry"],
        "Food": ["Juice","Ham","Rice","Oil"]
    }
)

# Group by col1 and col2 and combine col3 values
grouped = df.groupby(["Location", "Food"]).agg({"Location": lambda x: ", ".join(x)}).\
    drop("Location",axis=1)\
        # .reset_index()

print(grouped)
```

This solution results in a Multi-Index df, however, you could uncomment the `reset_index()` if you want to fill out the Locations and convert the index into columns.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
df_new = df.groupy(['Location'])['Food'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```